# single page application without using hashtag

Tags: web-applications, hashtag

Is it possible (and how) to do a single page application **without** using hashtag ?

On Google+ for example, we can click on some links, then the URL changes (but without hashtag) BUT we can't see a new page loading, only some part of the page is loading and refreshed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is using pushState.
Thank you @Len.

http://www.seomoz.org/blog/create-crawlable-link-friendly-ajax-websites-using-pushstate
http://html5.gingerhost.com/