# One-page navigation - remove # in url when using anchor tags in Wordpress menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, anchor

I have a site with menu tabs: Home, About, Work, Contact.
I'm using anchor tags for this one-page navigation.

But I don't want my url to update to something like this - http://example.com/#about or ../#work ..

I just want simply the default url on the address bar (http://example.com/) whenever I click on the menu tabs and jump to different sections of that one page.
I don't want to update the address bar.
How can I do that?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

set `id` for each your container of pages (about,work etc.) then set `href` like this

```
<a href="javascript:myscroll('about');">About</a>
```

then use this function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myscroll(myID){
    var offset = jQuery("#"+myID).offset()
    window.scrollTo(0,offset.top);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think you can create your own primary menu on menu page in wordpress

Comment: Yes, I can create custom links with anchor tags on menu page in WordPress. But I want to remove the # in url.

Comment: so you can create your menu by html and use my method or observe this site http://hayaliisler.com/  there is what you want

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks, for your help guys! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use javascript in order to achieve that. Im not sure you can do it without changing the url, but there is : [a nice way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page) to do it.

If you really dont want your url to change, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865182/single-page-application-without-using-hashtag)